# CosmosDB. Do change feeds trigger once data is eventually consistent?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

If I set my cosmos database to be eventually consistent, I’d like to know if change feeds are triggered once all regions are eventually consistent.   A use case might be to purge CDNs when all regions are consistent, so that there aren’t any racing conditions.

Thanks!~

Answer (score 0):

No. The Change Feed Trigger will trigger when the data is in the region it is reading from.

You can customize the region by the `PreferredLocations` attribute in the Trigger:

```
CosmosDBTrigger(
    databaseName: "yourDb",
    collectionName: "yourCollection",
    ConnectionStringSetting = "YourConnectionStringSettingName",
    PreferredLocations = "Central US",
    LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]
    IReadOnlyList<Document> documents,
```

Basically that property maps to [PreferredLocations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.preferredlocations?view=azure-dotnet#remarks).